# Insert Large data row by row in multiple reference tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, bulkinsert

> I went through a lot of posts on  **SO**. However, they do not fit my situation.

We have a situation where we want to store a large dataset on `sqlserver 2017` into multiple reference tables.

We have tried with `cursor` and it is working fine. However, we are concerned about the performance issue of loading large data(1+ million rows)

> **Example**
>
> **T_Bulk** is a input table, **T_Bulk_Orignal** is destination table and **T_Bulk_reference** is a reference table for **t_Bulk_orignal**

```
    create table T_Bulk
(
Id uniqueidentifier,
ElementType nvarchar(max),
[Description] nvarchar(max)
)

create table T_Bulk_orignal
(
Id uniqueidentifier,
ElementType nvarchar(max),
[Description] nvarchar(max)
)

create table T_Bulk_reference
(
Id uniqueidentifier,
Description2 nvarchar(max)
)

create proc UseCursor
(
@udtT_Bulk as dbo.udt_T_Bulk READONLY
)
as
begin 


DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier, @ElementType varchar(500), @Description varchar(500),@Description2 varchar(500)

    DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY  
    FOR   
    SELECT Id, ElementType, [Description]
    FROM dbo.T_BULK


    OPEN MY_CURSOR  
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Id, @ElementType, @Description,@Description2
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN   

    BEGIN Transaction Trans1

    BEgin TRy

            IF EXISTS (select Id from T_Bulk_orignal where ElementType=@ElementType and Description=@Description)
                select @Id = Id from T_Bulk_orignal where ElementType=@ElementType and Description=@Description

            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    insert T_Bulk_orignal(Id,ElementType,Description) values (@id, @ElementType,@Description)
                END


            INSERT T_Bulk_reference(Id,description2) 
            SELECT Id, Description2   
            FROM (select @Id as Id, @Description2 as Description2) F
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T_Bulk_reference C WHERE C.Id = F.Id and C.Description2 = F.Description2);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [DeleteTransaction]

        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Id, @ElementType, @Description,@Description2
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Trans1]

                    SELECT @@Error

    END CATCH   
    END  

    CLOSE MY_CURSOR  
    DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR

end
```

> We want this operation to execute in one go like bulk insertion however we also need to crosscheck any data discrepancy and if one row is not able to insert we need to rollback only that specific record

The only catch for bulk insertion is as there are reference table data present.

Please suggest best approach on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution to upload large file with a go like bulk insert.

There is a `Merge` statement present in SQL.

> The MERGE statement is used to make changes in one table based on
>   values matched from anther.   It can be used to combine insert,
>   update, and delete operations into one statement

So we can pass the data using `DataTable` to `StoredProcedure` and then Source will be your `UserDefinedDataTable` and Target will be your actual `SQL Table`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services). 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package

In SSIS you can create a data migration job that can do reference checks. You can set it up to fail ,warn or ignore errors at each stage. To find resources on this google for ETL and SSIS.

I have done jobs like yours on 50+ million rows.

Sure it takes a while, and it rolls back everything (if set up like that) on an error, but it is the best tool for this kind of job.

Comment: we want to have it in C# application level. I think SSIS will be a bit change in track plan we were having.